# Error: Operator '-' cannot be applied to types 'bigint' and 'number'.ts(2365) in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am working on a Web3 Project which is a combination of JavaScript + Typescript.

When I try to start my project it throws an error

```
Operator '-' cannot be applied to types 'bigint' and 'number'.ts(2365)
```

this error is showing on the below function on line number 10

```
let endBlock = startBlock + 99 > currentBlockNumber ? currentBlockNumber - 2 : startBlock + 99
```

Complete Function for the review:

```
async startBlockEvent() {
        let success = true
        schedule.scheduleJob("*/10 * * * * *", async () => {
            try {
                const provieder = new Web3(Config[this.chainId].prc)
                let currentBlockNumber = await provieder.eth.getBlockNumber()
                if (currentBlockNumber > this.asyncHeight + 3 && success) {
                    success = false
                    let startBlock = this.asyncHeight + 1
                    let endBlock = startBlock + 99 > currentBlockNumber ? currentBlockNumber - 2 : startBlock + 99
                    try {
                        let result = await this.blockTx.batchGetBlock(startBlock, endBlock, provieder)
                        let deployCollection = await this.insertCollection(result.collections)
                        let updateCollection = await this.updateCollection(result.updateCollections)
                        let updateHolder = await this.updateHolder(result.holders)
                        let insertTransfer = await this.insertTransfer(result.orders)
                        let updateDeposit = await this.updateDepositEvent(result.depositEvents)
                        let insertBlockHash = await this.insertBlockHash(result.blockHashs)
                        if (deployCollection && updateCollection && updateHolder && insertTransfer && updateDeposit && insertBlockHash) {
                            this.asyncHeight = endBlock
                            let updateConfig = this.sqlConfig ? this.sqlConfig : { chainId: this.chainId, asyncHeight: 0 }
                            updateConfig.asyncHeight = endBlock
                            this.sqlConfig = updateConfig
                            await this.Db.update("config", updateConfig)
                            console.log(`sync ${endBlock},deploy ${result.collections.length},mint ${result.mints.length} ,update collection ${result.updateCollections.length},wallet ${result.holders.length},request time ${result.requestTime} ms,handler data time ${result.handleDataTime} ms,validate block ${result.blockHashs.length}`)
                        }
                        success = true
                    } catch (error) {
                        console.log(error)
                        success = true
                    }
                }
            } catch (error) {
                success = true
            }
        })
    }
```

I am a newbie in typescript coding and I cloned the repository from GitHub so I didn't try much.

that's why I need StackOverflow's community help regarding this issue

Answer (score 1):

From the MDN topic on [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt#operators)...

> Most operators support BigInts, however most do not permit operands to be of mixed types — **both operands must be BigInt** or neither

To satisfy this condition, you can use a `BigInt` literal

```ts
currentBlockNumber - 2n
```

Comment: Thank You so much issue was fixed but after converting 2 to 2n two more errors came up but i figured them out using already asked questions on Stackoverflow